# Why am I Getting a "trade" Transaction Type from Coinbase API?

Tags: coinbase-api

According to the docs [Transaction types currently available](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?python#transaction-resource) "trade" isn't listed. Is this coming in from Coinbase Pro?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. On Coinbase you can now convert crypto to crypto, IE trade crypto.

Comment: It also appears on crypto-to-fiat type transactions.I got a XLM-USD transaction as a trade when I converted XLM to USD